# How to loop through cfspreadsheet headers?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfspreadsheet

I have an excel file that I am trying to read and then display the values of the headers in a drop down. The first row in my excel file has all of the values (header names).

I used the code below, but what happens is that all the header names appear in a single line with commas. I want the headers to be separated, so that it will appear in the drop down with many `<option>`, instead of a single `<option>`. How do I do that?

```
    <!-- Read the header values from excel -->
    <cfset spreadsheet = "uploads/spreadsheet.xlsx">

    <cfspreadsheet action="read" headerrow="1" src="uploads/spreadsheet.xlsx" query="excelHeader" rows="1" />

    <cfset excelHeaders = excelHeader.columnList>

    <!-- Display the header names as a dropdown -->
    <select name="id_headers">
        <option>
            #excelHeaders#
        </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: i've not done much with spreadsheets and coldfusion, but if excelHeader.columnList is coming back as a list, treat it as a list - loop through the list when you do your select box

Comment: I tried to loop using a list, `<cfloop query="excelHeader">#excelHeader.columnList#</cfloop>` and it still doesn't work the way I want.

Comment: like i said, i don't know much about excel and colfusion, but to loop over list, you want something like <cfoutput><cfloop index="headerItem" LIST="#excelHeaders#">#headerItem#</cfloop></cfoutput>

Comment: *I tried to loop using a list* No, that is a `query` loop. A "list" is just a string, delimited by some character. To loop through a "list", use the `list` attribute.  If you read the [cfloop documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cfloop-looping-over-a-list-a-file-or-an-array.html), the first two examples demonstrate how to loop through a "list".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code;

```
<!--- create new spreadsheet and populate with sample data --->
<cfset theSheet = SpreadsheetNew("Expenses")>
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(theSheet,"column1",1,1)> 
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(theSheet,"column2",1,2)>
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(theSheet,"column3",1,3)>
<cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(theSheet,"column4",1,4)>

<!--- Write the spreadsheet to a file, replacing any existing file. ---> 
<cfset pathToFile = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) & "newSpreadsheet.xls">
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#pathToFile#" name="theSheet" overwrite=true>

<!--- Read spreadsheet into query object ---> 
<cfspreadsheet action="read" headerrow="1" src="#pathToFile#" query="excelHeader" rows="1">

<!--- Display the header names as a dropdown --->
<cfoutput>
<select name="id_headers">
<cfloop list="#excelHeader.columnList#" index="option">
    <option>#option#</option>
</cfloop>
</select>
</cfoutput>
```

You can run this code snippet in [trycf](http://trycf.com/gist/e497270b80e67bf9287a508ab01d2d65/acf2016?theme=monokai)

Comment: @Leigh hey its nice. looks like more professional now. Thanks.